# Is it possible to know if a linear transformation is injective,surjective or bijective if it's not a finite dimension?

Tags: linear-algebra, linear-transformations

With finite dimension you can do a matrix representation a of a linear transformation but for example for the linear transformation of the integral operator is it one to one, onto or both? How do you deal with this type of cases?

Comment: thanks I edited the question

Comment: The answer is: it depends. There is no general method for determining injectivity/surjectivity.

Comment: With this level of detail, you do not deal with it at all. You need to specify the domain and the image set, and it very much relies on the specific case. For instance, there are results such as Fredholm's theorem: "If $T$ is an endomorphism of a Banach space and $I-T$ is compact, then $T$ is injective if and only if it is surjective."

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is no general method here.  It is notable, however, that we must *separately* check the conditions of injectivity and surjectivity for any linear transformation on infinite dimensional spaces (unlike in the case of square matrices).

The integral operator is a good example.  Let $C[0,1]$ denote the set of continuous (real-valued) functions over $[0,1]$.  Define $T:C[0,1] \to C[0,1]$ by
$$
T[f(x)] = \int_0^x f(t)\,dt
$$
This operator is *injective* because 
$$
T(f) = T(g) \iff
\int_0^x f(t)\,dt = \int_0^x g(t)\,dt \quad \forall x\in [0,1] \iff\\
\int_0^x [f(t) - g(t)]\,dt = 0 \quad \forall x\in [0,1] \implies\\
\frac {d}{dx} \left.\int_0^x [f(t) - g(t)]\,dt\right|_{x = x_0} = 0 \quad \forall x_0\in [0,1] \iff\\
f(x_0) - g(x_0) = 0 \quad \forall x_0 \in [0,1] \iff
f = g
$$
On the other hand, this operator fails to be *surjective*.  It is easy to verify that for any $f$, $[T(f)](0) = 0$ (that is, if we plug $x = 0$ into $T[f(x)]$, we get $0$).  It follows that we will never have $T[f(x)] = 5$, for example.  So, this operator is not surjective onto the space of continuous functions over $[0,1]$ (which includes the constant function $f(x) = 5$).